# Shopware 6 - adding new twig template to re-use elsewhere

Tags: twig, shopware6

I'm extending a twig template in shopware 6 and I'd like to add a new twig file that I can include multiple times with different parameters, instead of copying the content. I haven't found any resources on how to do that, although it seems like a very basic thing.
When I add a twig file in the same directory as the extended template file, I always get "unable to load template".

```
 {% sw_include '@MyPlugin/storefront/page/product-detail/page_product_detail_my_block.html.twig' %},
```

The file contains one twig block, which I wasn't able to include either. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

edit:  just found out that it can be included and embedded, but only if there's no block in the template file. If I include a block, it says

```
Unexpected token "end of statement block" ("name" expected). with these parameters: {"ratingSuccess":null,"themeIconConfig":[]}
```

Comment: What's up with the weird quotes? Also you blocks can never be included. You could use [`embed`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/embed.html) instead

Comment: I just found out that it can be included and embedded, but only if there's no block in the template file. If I include a block, it says Unexpected token "end of statement block" ("name" expected). with these parameters: {"ratingSuccess":null,"themeIconConfig":[]}

Comment: Well you need to name the block e.g. `{% block footer %}...{% endblock %}`

Comment: I did name the block of course, that doesn't seem to be the problem. Looks like I have to define all blocks somewhere because I don't see a difference to the existing vendor twig files.

Comment: Please post the template `page_product_detail_my_block.html.twig` as well

Comment: it doesn't work when the file is empty and not when it just contains {% block my-block %} {% endblock %}

Comment: `my-block` isn't a valid name, this will translate in substract the variable `block`  from the variable `my`. Consider using `my_block` or `myblock`